# What could be the cause of black streaks on the rubber seal on a front loading washer?

Tags: clothes-washer

I have a LG front loading washer (about 2 years old) that has worked fine for little bit over a year. Some time ago though black streak marks started appearing on the rubber that seals the washer door and on some of the fabrics, like towels. These marks appear during practically every wash, but not always to the same extent.

I typically wash clothes using tap water temperature, and use either Oxi Clean liquid detergent, or Ultra Tide powder. I live near Framingham, MA, USA, in case that matters (if it has something to do with the water supply?)

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: You didn't put how old your washer is, but I had a washer which the bearings (I believe) started going out in it and it transferred grease into the drum area, which stained a bunch of my clothes. This could be what is happening with you, though mine was not an LG.

Comment: @Paulster2, thank you for the comment (I have now updated my question with the age). What you are saying seems like it could have something to do with this problem.

Comment: Is that a biological or non-biological detergent that you're using? (Neither are available in my locale, so I'm not familiar with them)